# Is there a way to transition a border in with Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make it so that a border transitions on to the page smoothly once I reach a y point but I am having trouble with the transition animation. I'm using react and tailwind.

This is the code I have so far.

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const [navStyles, setNavStyles] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleNavStyles = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 80) {
        setNavStyles(true);
      } else {
        setNavStyles(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleNavStyles);
  }, []);

  
  return (
    <header className="sticky top-0 z-10 backdrop-blur-md ">
      <nav
        className={`mx-auto flex max-w-screen-sm items-center space-x-3 py-3 px-4 sm:py-5 sm:px-0 ${
          navStyles ? 'border-b transition duration-300 ease-in' : ''
        }`}
      >
      <div>Navbar</div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use transition-all instead of transition.